# PCLMULQDQ instruction in C inline asm

Tags: c, assembly, intel, inline-assembly, instructions

I want to use Intel's PCLMULQDQ instruction with inline assembly in my C Code for multiplying two polynomials, which are elements in GF(2^n). Compiler is GCC 4.8.1.
The polynomials are stored in arrays of uint32_t (6 fields big).

I already checked the web how to use the PCLMULQDQ instruction or CLMUL instruction set properly, but didn't found any good documentation.

I would really appreciate a simple example in C and asm of how to multiply two simple polynomials with the instruction. Does anybody know how to do it?

Besides are there any prerequisites (except a capable processor), like included libraries, compiler options etc.?

Comment: A quick search yielded http://download-software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/165685/clmul-wp-rev-2.01-2012-09-21.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found a solution. Thus for the record:

```
void f2m_intel_mult(
  uint32_t t, // length of arrays A and B
  uint32_t *A,
  uint32_t *B,
  uint32_t *C
)
{
    memset(C, 0, 2*t*sizeof(uint32_t));
    uint32_t offset = 0;
    union{ uint64_t val; struct{uint32_t low; uint32_t high;} halfs;} prod;

    uint32_t i;
    uint32_t j;
    for(i=0; i<t; i++){
        for(j=0; j<t; j++){

            prod.halfs.low = A[i];
            prod.halfs.high = 0;
            asm ("pclmulqdq %2, %1, %0;"
            : "+x"(prod.val)
            : "x"(B[j]), "i"(offset)
            );

            C[i+j] = C[i+j] ^ prod.halfs.low;
            C[i+j+1] = C[i+j+1] ^ prod.halfs.high;
        }
    }
}
```

I think it is possible to use 64bit registers for pclmulqdq, but I couldn't find out how to get this working with inline assembler. Does anybody know this?
Nevertheless it is also possible to do the same with intrinsics. (If you want the code just ask.)
Besides it is possible to optimize the calculation further with Karatsuba, if you know the size t of the arrays.

Comment: The [compiler output from this](https://godbolt.org/g/eaQrRx) is terrible in so many ways.  First, every `pclmul` is surrounded by a `movq` to copy a 64bit integer register to/from the low half of an xmm register.  Second, the `xor` operations are using 32bit operand-size, instead of merging into one 64bit xor with a memory destination.

Comment: And no, there is no form of pclmul that operates on integer/gp registers, [only xmm](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PCLMULQDQ.html).  It would be a lot more efficient to load 128 bits of data directly into an SSE vector, and use `pclmul` with different immediate offsets to do different parts of the multiply.  If you need to zero-extend `A` to 64bit elements, you can do that in SSE with `punpckldq` with a zeroed register.  (Or SSE4.1 `pmovzx`).  Actually you're doing the same for B, but implicitly.

Comment: You should do the XOR into `C` using SSE operations as well.  (load from C, `pxor`, store back.)  Anyway, you should definitely do this with intrinsics, not inline asm.  Your inline asm is correct and safe, but you're losing a lot of performance.

Comment: You can get `A[i]` loaded directly into an XMM register with [a small change to the constraints](https://godbolt.org/g/V1im9p).  I think your XOR into C overlaps between iterations of `j`, so it might actually be worse to do a single 64bit xor.  You'd get store-forwarding stalls from the overlap.  I was hoping the compiler would keep the high half in a register to be XORed next iteration, so each iter would have one reg-reg xor and one reg-mem xor, but it doesn't do that.  Anyway, the code I linked is better, but still bad compared to what should be possible.